# content in file do not exist in c proggram

Tags: c, io

How to make a file, i try to make a file.txt in c but i got an error, the program where i write successed execute but in file or in notepad the contents do not exist.

this my snippet of my code what I want to input to file.txt:

```
int a,b,c,d,e = 0,f = 0;
int check,check2,check3;
int *fptr;
fptr = fopen("file.txt","w");

printf("\nenter the amount of food to be purchased  : ");
check=scanf("%d", &b);
printf("\n");
            
if (check != 0) {
 for (a=1; a<=b; a++){
   printf("the price of food of- %d \t : ",a);
   check2=scanf("%d", &c);
   printf("\n");
                
   if (check2==0) {
     printf("Please enter in numeric !!\n");
     while ((getchar()) != '\n'); 
     system("PAUSE");
     goto cashier;
   }
   printf("the amount ordered \t : ");
   check3=scanf("%d", &d);
   printf("\n");
                
   if (check3==0) {
     printf("Please enter in numeric !!\n");
     while ((getchar()) != '\n'); 
     system("PAUSE");
     goto cashier;
   }
    e=c*d;
    f+=e;
}
printf("total price of food  \t : Rp.%d",f);
printf("\n");

char isTrue;
printf("\n\nPush [Y] to save a copy from your payment [T]\nTo Out\n:");
scanf(" %c",&isTrue);
if(isTrue == 'y' || isTrue == 'Y'){
fprintf(fptr, "the food you buy as much : %d\n", b);
fprintf(fptr, "total price of food : %d\n", f);

fclose(fptr);
goto cashier;

}
```

what should i do to fix this program ?

i want this fprintf(fptr, "the food you buy as much : %d\n", b);will execute and print it : "write the food you buy as much" in my notepad.and also in my notepad file.txt i do not write anything before and also i do not create this file.txt before

Comment: Try `fptr = fopen("C:/users/ryand/Desktop/file.txt","w"); if (!fptr) { perror("file.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Opening a file could fail. Test `fopen()`'s result for failure. Error checking is debugging for free.

Comment: Where is the label `cashier`?

Comment: still wrong, in my notepad the no one alphabet write. still not exist @pmg

Comment: Check the return values for `fopen` and `fprintf` to detect errors

Comment: how do i do that? @klutt

Comment: @ryand By reading the documentation for the functions to see what they return.